# An error corresponding to the additional file while using the duaiterate.py tool

Tags: python, sumo

By using the od2trips tool, I change a TAZ flow to the trip file named od2trips.xml. The vehicle type is emergency which is added by `--vtype` emergency in the command line. The additional file for this vehicle type is defined separately as add_file.xml. On the other hand, there is a background flow coming from the OSM called osm.passenger.trips.xml including veh_paasenger type id. I apply the duaiterate.py to routing the network as following:

```
~>duaiterate.py -n osm.net.xml -t osm.passenger.trips.xml,od2trips.xml duarouter--additional-files add_file.xml duarouter--vtype-output output.xml --additional add_file.xml --max-convergence-deviation 0.05 --last-step 70
```

After running, this error is displayed in the dua.log:

```
Error: The vehicle type 'veh_passenger' for vehicle 'veh0' is not known.
```

Could anyone give me any suggestions on how to deal with this error?
Best regards, Ali

Answer (score 0):

The additional vtype file needs to be passed to duarouter *and* sumo so instead of `duarouter--additional` try simply `--additional`.

Comment: would you look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Michael, I did my job as following but the error still exists in another form:

1. ~> od2trips -C od2trips.config.xml -n taz.xml -d od_file -o od2trips.xml --vtype emergency
2. ~ > od2trips -c od2trips.config.xml -n taz.xml -d od_file -o od2trips.xml --vtype emergency.
   In the next step, I added additional file with the option --additional as you mentioned:
3. ~ > duaiterate.py -n osm.net.xml -t od2trips.xml,osm.passenger.trips.xml --additional add_file.xml --max-convergence-deviation 0.05 --last-step 70
   But, this error is displayed :
   **Error: The vehicle type 'emergency' for vehicle '63' is not known** which is repeated for all vehicles with that type.

Comment: And 'emergency' is defined in add_file.xml?

Comment: Here it is:<additional>
    <vType id = "emergency" vClass = "emergency" color = "cyan" />  
</additional>

Comment: Dear Michael, would you check my reply?

Comment: I think you need to keep the `duarouter--vtype-output output.xml` option to keep duarouter from writing the vtype in the route file.

Comment: Michael, after the second step and generating the trips file of emergency vehicles, I added the vType definition to the top of the trips file and the problem was solved. By doing so, there is no need to separate additional file.